# What is the proper way to grab Authorization header from controller request object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I have two RSpec tests, a controller spec and a request spec, where I am making a GET request to the index action of the same controller. In both specs I am sending an Authorization header that contains an Oauth2 bearer token.

The problem I'm having is that depending on the type of spec, the header is stored on a different property of the request object. In the case of the request spec, it is available at `request.env["Authorization"]` and in the case of the controller spec, it is available at `request.session["Authorization"]`.

**Why is "Authorization" stored in different places for different types of specs? Is there somewhere I can find it for both specs?**

This `bearer_token` method is in the parent controller class where I'm grabbing the token from the header:

Works with `env` in the request specs:

```
def bearer_token
  pattern = /^Bearer /
  header  = request.env["Authorization"] # <= env
  header.gsub(pattern, '') if header && header.match(pattern)
end
```

Works with `session` in the controller specs:

```
def bearer_token
  pattern = /^Bearer /
  header  = request.session["Authorization"] # <= session
  header.gsub(pattern, '') if header && header.match(pattern)
end
```

Here is my request spec:

```
describe '' do
  let(:user) { Fabricate(:user) }

  describe 'accessing content with valid token' do
    let(:token) { OauthToken.create(user: user) }
    let(:auth_headers) { {
      'Authorization' => "Bearer #{token.access_token}",
      'HTTPS' => 'on'
    } }
    before { get api_v2_cats_path, {}, auth_headers }
    specify { response.status.should == 200 }
  end
end
```

Here is my controller spec

```
describe Api::V2::CatsController do
  let(:user) { Fabricate(:user) }

  describe ".index" do
    let(:token) { OauthToken.create(user: user) }
    let(:auth_headers) { {
      'Authorization' => "Bearer #{token.access_token}",
      'HTTPS' => 'on'
    } }

    it "should be valid" do
      get :index, { format: :json, page_size: 1 }, auth_headers
      @json = JSON.parse(response.body)
      @json.should_not be_nil
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I assumed that the API would be the same for the `get` method between a request and controller spec. In the controller spec, the third argument is a hash of sessions variables, not header variables. You can set the headers directly on the `@request` object like so:

```
describe Api::V2::CatsController do
  let(:user) { Fabricate(:user) }

  describe ".index" do
    let(:token) { OauthToken.create(user: user) }
    let(:auth_headers) { {
      'Authorization' => "Bearer #{token.access_token}",
      'HTTPS' => 'on'
    } }

    before do
      @request.env.merge!(auth_headers)
    end

    it "should be valid" do
      get :index, { format: :json, page_size: 1 }
      @json = JSON.parse(response.body)
      @json.should_not be_nil
    end
  end
end
```

Then the correct way to get the authorization header is using:

```
def bearer_token
  pattern = /^Bearer /
  header  = request.env["Authorization"] # <= env
  header.gsub(pattern, '') if header && header.match(pattern)
end
```

Comment: Just an improve, you can chage from `header.gsub(pattern, '') if header && header.match(pattern)` to `header.gsub(pattern, '') if header&.match(pattern)`

Comment: In my case I had to replace `request.env["Authorization"]` by `request.env["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"]`. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 13):

I found this.

https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/cf9d6a95e805bdddfa9c6b541631d51b3165bf23#diff-10b31f2069dfc4810229c8d60c3a4cda

in your controller, you can do something like this to get the header value.

```rb
def index

  header_value = request.authorization

end
```

Comment: This is very simple and works perfectly. Thanks. It helped me a lot.